# django log only receiving some activity

Tags: django, logging

Suddenly, as of this morning, our Django log does not display the logging from some requests, even though it appears that all requests are being serviced. Some requests display their logging in the log, others don't, but no one has changed anything. (I am the only person that has access to change anything). Does anyone know of a reason this could occur?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your log configuration.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to not be a Django issue at all. Unbeknownst to us, our web hosting provider adjusted an Apache policy regarding caching. Our iOS app now needs to specifically specify its cache policy in the HTTP header, or provide a unique URL parameter for the request, or Apache serves up stale responses. (The requests were not even reaching Django).